# Sass string evaluation. Is it possible?

Tags: sass

In Sass I have a string, for example `1px + 1px`.
Can I evaluate this string, using Sass, to get 2px result?

Answer (score 0):

You have an *actual* string?

as in `$foo: "1px + 1px";`

because no, in Sass you can't do anything like that, but you can just add numbers together so `10px + 100px` will equal 110px

See this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwEgrX